# Is there any function in the t-redux library that acts like the official connect function in redux?

Tags: reactjs

I need to connect various components to the state managed by t-redux, but t-redux seems to have only a withState() function that accepts only reducers and some initial state to work on. Hence every component seems to receive a "brand new state".

The library is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/t-redux

This is the official example

```
// import the needed modules 
import {withState, dispatcher, buildReducer} from 't-redux'


// this is a PORC (Plain Old React Component) 
class MyCounter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.plusOne = this.plusOne.bind(this)
  }
  plusOne() {
    // Dispacth the action (the content is optional) 
    dispatcher.dispatch({type: 'PLUS_ONE', content: this.props.counter})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Click count: {this.props.counter}</div>
        <button onClick={this.plusOne}>Add 1</button>
      </div>)
  }    
} 
// Build the reducers as a map ACTION:(state, action) => state 
const reducers = buildReducer({
  'PLUS_ONE': (state, action) => ({counter: state.counter + 1})
})

// Define the initial state 
const INITIAL_STATE = { counter: 0 }

// export the wrapped component passing the reducers and the initial state 
export default withState([reducers], INITIAL_STATE)(MyCounter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of t-redux's [withState](https://github.com/emadb/t-redux/blob/master/lib/withState.js), you'll see that each Higher Order Component contains its own state. The particular segment is here:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
    this.state = { innerState: initialState }
  }

componentWillMount() {
  this.regId = dispatcher.register(action => {
    const nextState = combineReducers(reducers, this.state.innerState, action)
    this.setState({innerState: nextState})
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  dispatcher.unregister(this.regId)
}
```

Essentially, it is using React's component state to store a redux pattern state. Since it is implemented this way, there isn't a way to have a single store for all your components.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. I misunderstood the t-redux philosophy.